# PSC and VC in Vmware

Tags: vsphere, vcenter

I am new to VSphere, when you want to install Vcenter, there are two options for deployment, embedded and external!
1. I don't even know what we are trying to deploy? is it anything more than PSC?
2. if that so is the PSC is our agent who is about to be installed on the host(which already had Vsphere intalled on), so we can connect to it from our PC which has the Vcenter on it?
3. why vsphere doesn't have enough files preinstalled, so you can connect with vCenter to it without uploading anything new to the Host(Server, Vsphere, whatever you wanna call it)?
4. Let's say we have completely another Vshpere server too, which I havn't touched it yet, but it has an IP address, can I add the IP address to vcenter without deploying anything so I can control it? Logically the answer should be no!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the 'New Installations' playlist to understand the differences in PSC and vCenter roles and their associated topologies: https://vspherecentral.vmware.com/t/vcenter-server/vcenter-lifecycle-install-upgrade-and-migrate-3/